# Refresh Listadapter with custom listview in Listfragment android

Tags: android, listview, customization, android-listfragment, listadapter

i used list adapter for setting values to listview.The values are loaded from webservice api.I need how to refresh the customized listview with list adapter in android.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Create a new adapter and set it to the ListView with `setAdapter` every time you reload your data.
2. Reuse the adapter (via `setData`or similar methods) and invoking `notifyDataSetChanged` after that, so the view is refreshed.

Comment: for listadapter there is no notifydatasetchanged method to refresh the listview.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` is in `ArrayAdapter`. Does your adapter extends it?

Comment: anyone plz tel me how to remove all the items from listview with customized layout??

Comment: Try setting adapter to `null`: `yourlistview.setAdapter(null)`

Comment: @junanjo Vega In listfragment there is no method for listview like notifydatasetchanged...

Comment: You will be using an ArrayList or an array (you may be passing it to the adapter's contructor) which is used in getView() to set values in your view. Clear that list or array and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: ya tried and setListadapter(null) also but no change...everytme the values again and again added in listview..

Comment: I am using ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to set values to customized listview

Comment: listfragment wont hav notifyDataSetChanged it will be there inside the adapter

Comment: on clicking item from listview i ve the option to edit & delete so after deleting i want to refresh my listview

Comment: remove that particular item i.e item at that position from ur arrayList and then call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: I have same problem with edit....i'm trying with all this thing....But what solution i try...again open activity.

Comment: @pkBhati i am using fragment..how can i call slide menu fragment from activity..how can i again open the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use notifyDataSetChanged() from the adapter, in order to do that your adapter needs extend BaseAdapter, so every time you change some data call the ,

```
instanceOfAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), entriesList1,
                                  R.layout.new_todo_single, new String[] { 
                                    "id","date","message","status"},
                                  new int[] { R.id.todot_id,R.id.todo_date,R.id.todo_message,R.id.todo_status});
                // setListAdapter(null);
                          // updating listview
                
                          setListAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: this is my adapter..it is in listfragment so there is no notifydatasetchanged method()..i m using customized listview with ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: As i understand, you want change refresh some data in your list in listview?, so, you need to catch the posotion, what you need change, manipulate then use adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You need call notifyDataSetChanged() in activity.

Comment: i am using Listfragment not activity...after deleting or editing items i need to refresh my listview

Comment: do you have a function to manipulate your list? so in this function you catch the potion using adapter.getItme(); change data and use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Your adapter extends from BaseAdapter?

Comment: where have to use, notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter or activity

Comment: on activity or fragment class

Comment: As i see in oficial documentation, SimpleAdapter extends from BaseAdapter, so you can use adpater.notifyDataSetChanged(); normally, try use SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter( getActivity(), entriesList1, R.layout.new_todo_single, new String[] { "id","date","message","status"}, new int[] { R.id.todot_id,R.id.todo_date,R.id.todo_message,R.id.todo_status}); // setListAdapter(adapter);// adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i never used ListAdapter, but you cantry use notifyAll() or notify() after change data

Comment: try made SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter( getActivity(), entriesList1, R.layout.new_todo_single, new String[] { "id","date","message","status"}, new int[] { R.id.todot_id,R.id.todo_date,R.id.todo_message,R.id.todo_status}); // setListAdapter(adapter);// adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must be using AsyncTask method to fetch data from WebService,Just override this method,and call notifyDataSetChanged method in onPostExecute like this.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
}
```